# Hibernate: Child id is null after merging parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've poured over similar questions on stackoverflow but I'm not able to find the right answer, so I'll post the question, if I may:

I have a typical one-to-many Parent-Child entities in a Spring Boot application. So, I create a new child, add it to the parent, and merge/flush/clear entity manager. Child entity gets saved in the database correctly, with a new ID, but the Child object's ID under the Parent object is zero. What am I missing that would force the refresh of the ID?

The code that creates a new child is in the same controller that fetches the Parent initially, so it's using the same DAO and the same entity manager.

Here's my code (entities are mostly generated by JPA):

Parent:

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Child> children;

    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return this.Children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public Child addChild(Child child) {
        getChildren().add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
        return child;
    }
}
```

Child:

```
@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    public Parent getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
@Repository
public class ParentDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void update(Parent parent) {
        entityManager.merge(parent);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Autowired
private ParentDao parentDao;

. . . createChild() {
    Child child = new Child();
    // Set the link on both sides of the relationship
    parent.addChild(child);
    parentDao.update(parent);
    // --> child.getId() == 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way merge() works when it is invoked on a new entity (Child in your case) it acts a persist() call with one small difference.

It only creates a copy of the passed entity and calls persist() on the copy.

So your Parent entity cannot see the change of id because it is holding the 'old' instance of the Child which was not persisted and eventually updated with a fresh id.

Hope that clears things up.

**Update**

To get the new state you need to:

**1)** change the transactional repository method to return the merge() value:

```
@Transactional
    public Parent update(Parent parent) {
        Parent newParent = entityManager.merge(parent);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
        return newParent
    }
```

**2)** change your service:

```
@Autowired
private ParentDao parentDao;

. . . createChild() {
    Child child = new Child();
    // Set the link on both sides of the relationship
    parent.addChild(child);
    Parent newParent = parentDao.update(parent);
    // --> newParent.getChildren(0).getId() == 0
}
```

Comment: i was under the impression that flush() would refresh the object and cascade it down, but i guess it doesn't... so what would be the answer then, how can i refresh the newly added children? do i need to flush() them as well?

Comment: thank you, maciej. so, while this appears to work, i still have a question - is there no option in hibernate to refresh the original parent object at all? i guess fundamentally i would want to unload object management to the orm, if i have to manage them with so much (error prone) effort that kind of defeats the purpose, doesn't it? and i would imagine that many, if not most users would want the same thing - just store my object and its new children in the db, and refresh it. and what if i had references to my parent object scattered all over the project, how would i consistently update them?

Comment: the second question in my comment above was rhetorical - i just don't think it makes sense for the ORM to force me to update all references to my object just to get the ID of the newly created child. also, in my case Parent is my User object, the one that got authenticated by the applicataion. replacing this object every time i add a child to it makes me little nervous and uneasy...

Comment: With my approach you dont have to update anything.. you just have to get fresh instance which is returned after the merge() operation.

Comment: Parent newParent = entityManager.merge(parent); <-- this produces a new pointer, correct? so all my existing references to parent will be pointing to the old, i guess now-detached instance. this is so messy... but anyway, i'll mark this as an answer since it answers the original question of how to get the newly created child's id. i'll keep on researching to see if there's a way to refresh the original pointer. thanks very much!

Comment: Welcome. Glad it gave you some value